# nodemon crashing after entering data

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

Currently working thru a Web dev bootcamp and while making a newsletter for one of the projects I kept receiving errors after entering info. Looked over my code and made sure there were no typos and I still got the error.

This is what I keep getting. Installed npm request again to fix it, didnt work. Another problem I think it could be is my mailchimp url and method in my js file.

```js
/Users/princetonhardy/Desktop/Newsletter-Signup/app.js:54
  if (response.statusCode === 200) {
  ^

ReferenceError: response is not defined
    at Request._callback (/Users/princetonhardy/Desktop/Newsletter-Signup/app.js:54:3)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/princetonhardy/Desktop/Newsletter-Signup/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/princetonhardy/Desktop/Newsletter-Signup/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/princetonhardy/Desktop/Newsletter-Signup/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Here is the js file.

```
//jshint esversion: 6


const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");


const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){

var firstName = req.body.fName;
var lastName = req.body.lName;
var email = req.body.email;

var data = {
  members: [
    {
    email_address: email,
    status: "subscribed",
    merge_fields: {
      FNAME: firstName,
      LNAME: lastName
    }
  }
  ]
};

var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);


var options = {
  url: "https://us20.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/5c3fdbcbe1",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Princeton1 7f7099a5cbc93e527c69585bd6c01917-us20"
  },
  body: jsonData
};


request(options, function(error, repsonse, body){
  if (error) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
} else {
  if (response.statusCode === 200) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
    res.send("successfully Subscribed");
  } else {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
  }
}
});


});


app.post("/failure.html", function(req, res){
  res.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Its up on 3000");

});
```

Comment: We'll have to see your code to help you out; it definitely looks like a bug in your application; that call stack shows you the line that it's taking place on.

Answer (score 0):

Change `repsonse` to `response`.

(trying to hit 30 char minimum)